# Removing alert() function crashes my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I try to create a running infotext on an infoscreen. The Text starts running from the right corner of the screen and leaves on the left side. This process repeats without a limit recursively.

Everything seems to work great, but when I remove the alert after debugging, the text don't start running from the right corner but from the left. Also the programm runs only one time.

HTML:

```js
function setStaticData() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('headerWidth', document.getElementById('header').scrollWidth);
}

function getStaticData() {
  return sessionStorage.getItem('headerWidth');
}

function animation() {

  //get element, its width & time param
  var header = document.getElementById('header');
  var headerWidth = getStaticData();
  var headerTime = header.innerHTML.length * 0.3;
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

  //clean all
  header.style.transition = 'none';
  header.style.marginLeft = windowWidth + 'px';

  alert("baba"); //BAD BOY

  //animate text
  header.style.transition = 'margin linear ' + headerTime + 's';
  header.style.marginLeft = '-' + headerWidth + 'px';

  //wait and repeat
  var delay = headerTime * 1000 + 1000;
  setTimeout(animation, delay);
}

//first call
window.onload = function() {
  setStaticData();
  animation();
};
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: black;
  background-color: #bbc8d9;
}

header {
  font-family: calibri, arial;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">+++ News, More News, Another Thing & something else +++</header>
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If I remove the bad boy [alert("baba");] it doesn't work, like I mentioned above.

I going crazy! Can you pls help me?

Comment: Can I ask why are you using sessionStorage to store the header width?
its not exactly the right use for it...

Comment: Yes you can :)
The scrollWidth becomes bigger with every time I loop my function.
So I need to use the original scrollWidth, which is saved local,  to reset the startposition of the text after every loop.

Comment: Yes but a simple variable for it would be enough, no need to save it in sessionStorage...

Comment: @OriShalom, looks like someone stores pencils in the fridge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that changes to the style of an element are not processed until the Javascript returns to the main event loop and the page is rendered. If you make two assignments to a style, the browser only sees the final result. So when you set `marginLeft` to the window width and then set it to `"-" + headerWidth + "px"`, only the second change is processed, so that's where the animation starts from.

The `alert()` causes the page to be rendered while it's waiting for your response (although I think this may be browser-dependent), which is why it works with that.

A simple solution is to put the second assignment in a `setTimeout()`, so it will be executed asynchronously after returning.

```js
function setStaticData() {
  //sessionStorage.setItem('headerWidth', document.getElementById('header').scrollWidth);
}

function getStaticData() {
  return document.getElementById('header').scrollWidth; //sessionStorage.getItem('headerWidth');
}

function animation() {

  //get element, its width & time param
  var header = document.getElementById('header');
  var headerWidth = getStaticData();
  var headerTime = header.innerHTML.length * 0.3;
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

  //clean all
  header.style.transition = 'none';
  header.style.marginLeft = windowWidth + 'px';

  //alert("baba"); //BAD BOY

  //animate text
  setTimeout(function() {
    header.style.transition = 'margin linear ' + headerTime + 's';
    header.style.marginLeft = '-' + headerWidth + 'px';
  }, 0);

  //wait and repeat
  var delay = headerTime * 1000 + 1000;
  setTimeout(animation, delay);
}

//first call
window.onload = function() {
  setStaticData();
  animation();
};
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: black;
  background-color: #bbc8d9;
}

header {
  font-family: calibri, arial;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">+++ News, More News, Another Thing & something else +++</header>
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @KoshVery I think you don't understand the problem we're trying to solve. It's not the error from `localStorage`, which is just because SO runs snippets in a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the snippet below. I don't use `sessionStorage` as it is designed for a different purpose. I don't use `setTimeout` to wait for the styles to be applied.

I start the animation then restart it on `transitionend` event.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var header = document.getElementById('header');
  animation();

  header.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    header.style.transition = 'none';
    header.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    animation();
  });

  function animation() {
    var t = header.offsetWidth / 70,
      tx = header.scrollWidth;

    header.style.transition = 'transform ' + t + 's linear';
    header.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + tx + 'px)';
  }
};
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #bbc8d9;
}

header {
  font: 100px sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">+++ News, More News, Another Thing & something else +++</header>
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with session storage.

Comment: Your snippet has the same problem as the original code.

Comment: My snippet works without a wrong use of sessionStorage and extraneous timeout.

Comment: When I run your code snippet, it doesn't work properly. The animation starts with the message at the left, not entering from the right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before I used margin to solve my problem, I thought about that kind of listener, but didn't get this one.

But repeat doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Comment: @DataCent, thanks for your interest. Looks like Chrome does not support `ontransitionend` as a property. I've updated my answer to use `addEventListener` notation. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think i fixed it. Its the timing problem just delay the animate call. 1s

```
function animation() {

            //get element, its width & time param
            var header = document.getElementById('header');
            var headerWidth = getStaticData();
            var headerTime = header.innerHTML.length * 0.3;
            var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

            //clean all
            header.style.transition = 'none';
            header.style.marginLeft = windowWidth+'px';

            // delay it for 1000ms
            setTimeout( 
            function(){
                //animate text
                header.style.transition = 'margin linear '+headerTime+'s';
                header.style.marginLeft = '-'+headerWidth+'px';    

                //wait and repeat
                var delay = headerTime * 1000 + 1000;
                setTimeout(animation, delay);
            }, 1000);

        }
```